# Android view is see-through, despite not being transparent

Tags: android

As the title suggests, the chevron on the slider handle seems to be transparent, and the slider's text is visible through it, despite never adding such logic. Does anybody know what could be causing this? I've tried adding elevation and changing the background color slightly so they don't match, but nothing seems to work.

###### fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slider_root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/slider_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/my_org_blue" />

    <com.myorg.SliderHandle
        android:id="@+id/slider_handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slider_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Slide to pay
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

###### slider_handle.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/handle_background" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/handle_chevron" />

</FrameLayout>
```

###### handle_chevron.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="14dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="14"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/my_org_blue"
        android:pathData="..."
</vector>
```

###### SliderHandle.kt

```
internal class SliderHandle @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.slider_handle, this)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: this `com.myorg.SliderHandle` package is your code or you use external library?

Comment: it's my company's internal package

Comment: Is the chevron actually see-through, or is the "Slide to pay" text drawn later than your chevron? Maybe change your text from white to red for testing.

Comment: They should be drawn at the same time. And changing the color doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: can you show `SliderHandle` class?